# @Produces({"application/x-javascript"}) not working in spring mvc version 4.0.5.RELEASE

Tags: javascript, json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have created a spring application and i am also using webservices.

I want to use jsonp callback function for which the media type should be {"application/x-javascript"}. This seems not to be working. it is returning json object and not javascript.
Here is the code..

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "widget", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 @Produces({"application/x-javascript"})
  public @ResponseBody JSONWithPadding displayWidgetPage(Model model, HttpServletResponse                              
 response,HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String callback = request.getParameter("callback");

    PointsInfo pointsInfo =new PointsInfo();
    pointsInfo.setUsername("json");

    return new JSONWithPadding(pointsInfo,callback);
    }
```

I checked using the rest client...

It says the content type is : Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

It has to be : Content-Type: application/javascript;charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

I think that you're mixing Jersey's [@Produces](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/jax-rs.html#d4e144) and [JSONWithPadding](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.1.5.1/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/json/JSONWithPadding.html) with Spring MVC, and Jersey's @Produces will not take any effect there.

If you're looking for a way to implement JSON-P with Spring MVC only, take a look at

http://patrickgrimard.com/2010/07/28/tutorial-implementing-a-servlet-filter-for-jsonp-callback-with-springs-delegatingfilterproxy/

or if you're able to upgrade to the version 4.1 or above

http://spring.io/blog/2014/07/28/spring-framework-4-1-spring-mvc-improvements

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Spring version older than 3.1.1.RELEASE. If you are looking to set your response's media type, it should be in the RequestMapping annotation like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list/rideLogs/{rideId}", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
         produces = YOUR_MEDIA_TYPE)
```

That being said application/javascript isn't a valid media type for Spring. You can refer to values of MediaType class.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html

Comment: it should work with the pre-defined media types in MediaType class